# Android-N does not start Activity after Direct boot

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

Starting with Android N, a device that has been powered on can boot into a new mode called **Direct Boot** before the user has a chance to unlock it for the first time.

To make any of the app components aware of direct boot, there is new XML attribute `android:directBootAware`. In the [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/direct-boot.html) it is mentioned that direct mode is not for every app but for some specific use cases such as Alarm clock app or Notification sending app etc.

Just for experiment purpose, I created a simple app with one activity that has set `android:directBootAware` in AndroidManifest.xml file.

I ran this app on Android-N based Emulator.

However, I could not see my app's Activity which I set as `android:directBootAware` launched after my Emulator booted. Didn't it supposed to start the app components after boot?

Comment: I think the documentation could use some work. I would focus on this: "Encryption aware components can register to receive a `LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast message from the system when the device has been restarted. At this point device encrypted storage is available, and your component can execute tasks that need to be run during Direct Boot mode, such as triggering a scheduled alarm."

Comment: @CommonsWare I added the intent-filter `<action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />` to the Activity. And re-installed the app. And then re-boot. Still Unable to see my app's activity running on Android-n emulator. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: An `Activity` is not a `BroadcastReceiver`. My interpretation of the documentation is that `LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLET‌​ED` is just a broadcast.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, it is a Broadcast. but it seems docs makes it clear that any app component(Activity,Service, Provider and BroadcastReceiver) could be made direct boot aware with `android:directBootAware=”true”`. There is a dev. [blogspot](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/04/developing-for-direct-boot.html) too which I read that seems to be saying the same thing. Hence, I tried to check with Activity component by making it direct boot aware.

Comment: "that seems to be saying the same thing" -- actually, my interpretation of the blog post is that only a `BroadcastReceiver` would be run automatically. Admittedly, this whole area is confusing. I haven't played with it yet, as I am waiting for final Android 7.0 builds and hardware.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried with both `Service` and `BroadcastReceiver`. I set them `android:directBootAware=true` in AndroidManifest and also set their intent-filter with `<action android:name="androi‌​d.intent.action.LOCKE‌​D_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`. Still I could not see Service or BroadcastReceiver getting started after re-boot. I tested by simply keeping logs in Service's onCreate and Receiver's onReceive...but no luck! Confusing :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120983/discussion-between-aadtechnical-and-commonsware).